# mdframed-Put something on the start of one vertical left rule

Tags: formatting, mdframed

I would like to obtain something like in the following picture (I've put Z! instead of the danger symbol).

[image: Formatting]

In the following code, I would like to put the danger symbol on the vertical rule.

I think that can be done by putting one kind of box on the start of the vertical rule, the box would have a white background and would contain the symbol.

If the symbol can be add at every new page where the verical rule is broken, it would be great.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[x11names, svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{fourier-orns}

    \definecolor{warningColor}{named}{Red3}
    \newcommand{\warningSymbol}{\raisebox{\depth}{\danger}}

    \newenvironment{Warning}{%
        \bigskip
        \begin{mdframed}[%
            topline=false,%
            rightline=false,%
            bottomline=false,%
            innertopmargin=0.4em,%
            innerbottommargin=0.4em,%
            innerrightmargin=0.7em,%
            rightmargin=0.7em,%
            innerleftmargin=0.7em,%
            leftmargin=0.7em,%
            linewidth=.2em,%
            linecolor=warningColor%
        ]
        \color{warningColor}
    }{%
        \end{mdframed}%
        \bigskip
    }

    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{Warning}
    \lipsum
\end{Warning}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you don't need the page breaking mdframed provides, have a look at the `bclogo` package - it provides such functionality & has several graphs, including the danger sign, built in (last time I looked the documentation was in french only, but the examples are clear enough).

Comment: I know the bclogo package. Indeed the last development version used mdframed so as to allow page breakings. See this page : http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/G/bclogo/dev/ . Indeed I prefer to do it by hand so as to produce more personal formatting like the one proposed by Marco Daniel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I provide a solution with TikZ which works similar with `framemethod=pstricks`. If you are using `framemethod=default` you must patch internal commands. This based on the implementation. The standard implementation doesn't know "nodes".

To define your requested environment I suggest the following.

First define a tikzstyle which stands for the node placing the danger symbol. Instead of original definition with `raisebox` you can work with the tikz option `scale`. In the next step I define a global style by `\mdfdefinestyle`. The package `mdframed` offers the option `fontcolor` which should be used. In your case by setting `\color{warningColor}` after the beginning of the environment the color modification has no effect if the box is splitted.

To place a node over the left line on every part of the output I use the new options (version 1.5) `singleextra`, `firstextra`, `secondextra` and `middleextra`. These options added the material to the tikz-environment so that you can modify the output. Therefor I go back to the defined coordinates of mdframed `P` (left bottom point of the box) and `O` (right lower point of the box) and compute the position. In the example the position is set to `0.5`. You can simple set `1` for the top and `0` for the bottom.

First step:

```
\tikzset{
  warningsymbol/.style={
      rectangle,
      draw=warningColor,
      fill=white,
      scale=1,
      overlay}
}
```

Second step:

```
\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{%
 hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
 skipabove=12,skipbelow=12pt,
 innertopmargin=0.4em,%
 innerbottommargin=0.4em,%
 innerrightmargin=0.7em,%
 rightmargin=0.7em,%
 innerleftmargin=1.7em,%
 leftmargin=0.7em,%
 middlelinewidth=.2em,%
 linecolor=warningColor,%
 fontcolor=warningColor,%
 firstextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 secondextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 middleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
}
```

With theses modification you get the following output:

[image]
[image]

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\definecolor{warningColor}{named}{Red3}
\tikzset{
  warningsymbol/.style={
      rectangle,
      draw=warningColor,
      fill=white,
      scale=1,
      overlay}
}

\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{%
 hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
 skipabove=12,skipbelow=12pt,
 innertopmargin=0.4em,%
 innerbottommargin=0.4em,%
 innerrightmargin=0.7em,%
 rightmargin=0.7em,%
 innerleftmargin=1.7em,%
 leftmargin=0.7em,%
 middlelinewidth=.2em,%
 linecolor=warningColor,%
 fontcolor=warningColor,%
 firstextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 secondextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 middleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
}

\newmdenv[style=warning]{Warning}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{Warning}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{Warning}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{Warning}
    \lipsum\lipsum[1]
\end{Warning}

\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives an easy to understand example. It should be added to the documentation.

Comment: @projetmbc: Please see my updated answer.