# Text environment with vertical header and border

Tags: macros, environments, framed

I have no experience with creating latex environments, so I hope that someone would be so kind helping me trying to create a new text environment with a border and a vertical header to the right of the text area.

I've tried to depict it using my MS Paint skills:

[image]

Is there anyone who can help me create such an environment or give me some hints on how to do it? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! A suggestion: http://marcodaniel.github.com/mdframed/ or see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52023/mdframed-put-something-on-the-start-of-one-vertical-left-rule

Comment: A truly awesome package. Thank you very much for sharing it Marco. If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment I suggest the package `mdframed`. I am sure the packages `framed` or `tcolorbox` are also able to do this.

All listed options can be found in the documentation. I also recommend the example of the question [mdframed-Put something on the start of one vertical left rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52023/mdframed-put-something-on-the-start-of-one-vertical-left-rule) where I explain most of the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%need for tikz let operation
\usepackage{kantlipsum}%filling text

\newmdenv[%
 skipabove=\topskip,%
 skipbelow=\topskip,%
 rightmargin=.5cm,%
 leftmargin=2cm, %
 middlelinewidth=2pt,%
 middlelinecolor=blue!70,%
 firstextra={\path[overlay]  let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+1*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[rotate=90,anchor=east,yshift=2em,font=\bfseries\large] {Short Header};},%
 singleextra={\path[overlay] let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+1*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[rotate=90,anchor=east,yshift=2em,font=\bfseries\large] {Short Header};},%
]{myframe}


\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\begin{myframe}
\kant[2]
\end{myframe}

\kant[3]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to add an option for changing the header in their digression-environment (Example 6 here: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/marcodaniel/mdframed/mdframed-example-texsx.pdf), so you can use the package something like this: \begin{mdframed}[style=digressionarrows]{Header of the environment}. Do you know how to do that? :-)

Comment: @TommyJakobsen: Yes ;-). I recommend to ask a new question. I can't answer it know. If you ask in 2 hours again, I will be back.

Comment: Yes of course. Here it is :-) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54754/mdframed-digressionarrows-style-with-custom-header