# Suppressing the frametitle in mdframed tikz frames

Tags: mdframed

I really like the digression style created in
[mdframed digressionarrows style with custom header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54754/mdframed-digressionarrows-style-with-custom-header). I would like to extend it even further by displaying the `frametitle` (if it is defined) after the custom `digressiontitle` (i.e. Side note or Info). So far this is what I managed to do:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}
       \usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \makeatletter
    \mdf@do@stringoption{digressiontitle=={Digression}}
    \tikzset{
      excursus arrow/.style={%
           line width=2pt,
          draw=gray!40,
          rounded corners=2ex,
          },
       excursus head/.style={
          fill=white,
          font=\bfseries\sffamily,
          text=gray!80,
          anchor=base west,
      },
    }
    \mdfdefinestyle{digressionarrows}{%
       singleextra={%
                \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
                \path let \p1=(Q), \p2=(O) in (\x1,{(\y1-\y2)/2}) coordinate (M);
                \path [excursus arrow, round cap-to]
                            ($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (M) |- %
                            ($(Q)+(12em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
                            ++(23em,2ex);
                \ifx\empty\mdf@frametitle\empty
                   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle};
                \else
                   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle:\space\mdf@frametitle};
                \fi},
       firstextra={%
                \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
                \path [excursus arrow,-to] (O) |- %
                            ($(Q)+(12em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
                            ++(23em,2ex);
                \ifx\empty\mdf@frametitle\empty
                   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle};
                \else
                   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle:\space\mdf@frametitle};
                \fi},
       secondextra={%
                \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
                \path [excursus arrow,round cap-]($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (Q);},
       middleextra={%
                \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
                \path [excursus arrow](O) -- (Q);},
       middlelinewidth=2.5em,middlelinecolor=white,
       hidealllines=true,topline=true,
       innertopmargin=0.5ex,
       innerbottommargin=2.5ex,
       innerrightmargin=2pt,
       innerleftmargin=2ex,
       skipabove=0.87\baselineskip,
       skipbelow=0.62\baselineskip,
    }
    \makeatother

    \newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Info]{info}
    \newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Side note]{sidenote}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{sidenote}[frametitle=A side note 1]
    \lipsum[3]
    \end{sidenote}

    \begin{info}[frametitle=My frame]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum
    \end{info}

    \end{document}
```

The problem with this solution is that the `frametitle` is still being displayed. Is there an easy way to suppress the display of `frametitle` by `mdframed`?

**Update:**

Here is the picture which hopefully illustrates the problem:
[image: Image showing duplicate title]

As you can see, "A side note 1" appears twice, once in gray after Side note:, which should be kept, and once inside the frame above the text. This I want to suppress.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I guess I wasn't clear enough - I'll add a picture to the question - the way I programmed it, the `frametitle` will appear both after Info: or Idea: and inside the frame. I would like to suppress the second appearance (inside the frame). Is this more clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to define a new key for your title; in this way, both elements (the `frametitle` and your title) are independent. This is simply done using something like

```
\def\mdf@mytitle{}
\define@key{mdf}{mytitle}{%
  \def\mdf@mytitle{#1}}
```

Now you can use `\mdf@mytitle` instead of the frametitle key in your internal settings and the `mytitle` key in the options for your `mdframe`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
\def\mdf@mytitle{}
\define@key{mdf}{mytitle}{%
  \def\mdf@mytitle{#1}}

\mdf@do@stringoption{digressiontitle=={Digression}}
\tikzset{
  excursus arrow/.style={%
   line width=2pt,
  draw=gray!40,
  rounded corners=2ex,
  },
   excursus head/.style={
  fill=white,
  font=\bfseries\sffamily,
  text=gray!80,
  anchor=base west,
  },
}
\mdfdefinestyle{digressionarrows}{%
   singleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path let \p1=(Q), \p2=(O) in (\x1,{(\y1-\y2)/2}) coordinate (M);
\path [excursus arrow, round cap-to]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (M) |- %
($(Q)+(12em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
++(23em,2ex);
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle:\space\mdf@mytitle};
\fi},
   firstextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,-to] (O) |- %
($(Q)+(12em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
++(23em,2ex);
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle:\space\mdf@mytitle};
\fi},
   secondextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,round cap-]($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (Q);},
   middleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow](O) -- (Q);},
   middlelinewidth=2.5em,middlelinecolor=white,
   hidealllines=true,topline=true,
   innertopmargin=0.5ex,
   innerbottommargin=2.5ex,
   innerrightmargin=2pt,
   innerleftmargin=2ex,
   skipabove=0.87\baselineskip,
   skipbelow=0.62\baselineskip,
}
\makeatother

\newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Info]{info}
\newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Side note]{sidenote}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidenote}[mytitle=A side note 1]
\lipsum[3]
\end{sidenote}

\begin{info}[mytitle=My frame]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum
\end{info}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem :-) I guess I need to learn some more about TeX internals...