# Open ended frame with framed.sty

Tags: page-breaking, framed

I made a frame using the [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package. When a pagebreak breaks it, it is divided in two separate frames. I would like the bottom and top of these two frames to be open, and an `oframe` option is supposed to do this, but I can't seem to implement it.

My frame contains multiple lines of text and `\includegraphics`.

This is what I want to frame:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{image.jpg}
\end{center}
(Text)
\begin{center}
Text\\
Text\\
\end{center}
```

I tried this to no avail:

```
\begin{oframed}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{image.jpg}
\end{center}
(Text)
\begin{center}
Text\\
Text\\
\end{center}
\end{oframed}
```

The option `framed` instead of `oframed` works though. It seems I need to use the `\MakeFrame` command in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For open ended boxes you can use the [mdframed](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{backgroundcolor=red!10}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4] \bigskip
\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault,
frametitle={Open frame example}]
\lipsum[5-6]    
\end{mdframed}
\bigskip \lipsum[7-8] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't like the way `mdframed` looks.

Comment: @Man: `mdframed` is highly customizable so the way it looks depends on you ;-) See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57739/4918 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47537/4918

Comment: Could some able person please supply me the code for an open ended box with a simple black frame a la `\begin{framed}`?

Comment: Forget it folks! The default settings did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @Man: What do you mean with "I don't like the way mdframed looks." Can you specify this.